# Question Dashboard (Greasemonkey Script)

Tags: script, javascript, greasemonkey

Question Dashboard for stackoverflow.com (plus meta, serverfault and superuser) - page analyzed and indicators shown at the top of the question, just under the title, for key information.

**Downloads:**

> [stackoverflowQdashboard hosted at wittman.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20210301045851/https://wittman.org/projects/stackoverflowqdashboard/)
>
> [stackoverflowQdashboard hosted at github](https://gist.github.com/wittman/244842)
>
> > *Greasemonkey (Firefox) and GreaseKit (Safari) compatible.*

**Screenshot A:**

[image: stackoverflow Question Dashboard Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [wittman.org](https://wittman.org/projects/stackoverflowqdashboard/stackoverflowQdashboard-sm-screenshot.png))</sub>

Here are your configuration options:

```
/*** Configuration ************************/

//Modules and Other Options

// Easteregg Users
var mod_eastereggUsersEnabled = true; //If true then indicates if specific users are found (could be considered an easter egg - the three Js and the author of this user script)

// Early Adopter User
var mod_earlyadopterEnabled = true; //If true then indicates if an early adopter user is found (based on configuration var earlyadopter_threshold)
var earlyadopter_threshold = 12000; //Early Adopter Threshold (minimum user id integer value) at which point users there and lower are considered early adopters of SO

// Answer Vote Count
var mod_answerVotecountEnabled = true; //If true then indicates the answer with the greatest vote-count on the page

// Comments
var mod_commentsEnabled = true; //If true then indicates if one or more comments from Warm to Supernova (thresholds of comment-vote-count) are found.

// User Reputation
var mod_userRepEnabled = true; //If true then indicates if one or more users that meet a certain threshold are found (10k+ User and "Help a Noobie" (user with rep in the single digits)
var userRep10kEnabled = true; //[Config var mod_userRepEnabled must be true to enable] If true then indicates if at least one user with 10,000 rep value is found
var userRep1kEnabled = true; //[Config var mod_userRepEnabled must be true to enable] If true then indicates if at least one user with 1,000 rep value is found
var userRepNoobEnabled = true; //[Config var mod_userRepEnabled must be true to enable] If true then indicates "Help a Noobie" if at least one user with rep value 1 to 9 is found

// Track (words/phrases to be detected are text in the question page)
var mod_trackEnabled = true; //Set true to enable tracking words/phrases
var trackArr = ['cobol', 'forth', 'lisp', 'best practices', 'Babbage']; //If trackEnabled is true, then this array of words/phrases (case insensitive) is tracked (if found on question page, indicated in Question Dashboard. A regex is used, so there's a performance consideration, but the advantage is there shouldn't be much substring false positives (e.g. var trackArr = ['.NET', 'C#']; ~~~ Given 'The .NET framework blah blah blah' then '.NET' WILL match ~~~ Given: 'Use www.example.net as an example site.' then '.net' WILL NOT match.

// Other Options
var subdashboardEnabled = true; //If true then the Sub Question Dashboard rendered (it is a copy of the Question Dashboard located above the Answer Paging controls ([1][2]...Next)
var communityWikiIndicatorEnabled = true; //If true then indicates if Question is a Community Wiki
var extraIndicatorEnabled = false; //Left border of main content section gets set to dotted gray if Community Wiki, or orange if regular question and some component for Question Dashboard is detected.
var meEnabled = true; //If true, indicate if I (the logged-in user) is found in the Answer section

/*****************************************/
```

---

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

---

**Screenshot B:**

[image: stackoverflow Question Dashboard User Rep Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [wittman.org](https://wittman.org/projects/stackoverflowqdashboard/stackoverflowQdashboard-rep-screenshot.png))</sub>

---

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

---

**Screenshot C:**

[image: meta.stackoverflow Question Dashboard Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [wittman.org](https://wittman.org/projects/stackoverflowqdashboard/stackoverflowQdashboard-track-screenshot.png))</sub>

---

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

---

Note: Originally posted here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/31486/question-dashboard-greasemonkey-script on Dec 1 '09.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Chrome 9.0.597.98 :'(

Comment: "Greasemonkey (Firefox) and GreaseKit (Safari) compatible." Sorry.

Comment: Link at bottom of this post is now dead.